# How do I fix this weird vertex artefact

Tags: mesh, vertices, error

[image]

Hey guys, I am following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DncP3mKJB2M

At around 46:07, There is this weird thing happening on the sole mesh of my project which is completely different from the tutorial, how do I fix it?

here's the file : [image]

Comment: I don't know anything but did you check your normals/backfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you forgot to set bevel for this edge:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Crantisz, new to blender so didn't notice that, rookie mistake, also mean bevel weight was a bit tricky for me, looked at the tut for a min to realize it